# Not able to connect to heroku redis

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, heroku-redis

```
const redis = require("redis");

let client = redis.createClient({
    host: process.env.host,
    port: process.env.port,
    password:process.env.password
});

(async () => {
    client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
    await client.connect();
    console.log("connected to redis")
  })();
```

I have added redis-heroku addon to my project, Now I am trying to access it from my code but its giving me this error: "AuthError: ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set".

Also when I am trying to connect from terminal, I am able to connect to it but when I type any redis command , I get this "Error: Connection reset by peer".

If I am using this on my localsystem and local redis server its working fine

it will be helpful if anyone can provide me a working code of heroku redis, I think redis has two urls: REDIS_URL, REDIS_TLS_URL. The problem might be arising because of this tls(more secure)

Kinldy help me
Thanks

Comment: Which version of node-redis are you using?

Comment: I am using "redis": "^4.0.1" and redis-cli 5.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Heroku redis does not expose a `host`, `port`, and `password` variables. Instead they expose a `REDIS_URL` that contains all of those things in one string.

I believe you need to call createClient like this...

```js
createClient({
  url: process.env.REDIS_URL
});
```

Comment: Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1142:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'ip',
  port: 10080
}

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am getting this error with your code @TerribleDev

Comment: @KanavRaina I actually think this answer looks better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65563689/3671357

Comment: const redis = require("redis");

const redisUrl = process.env.REDIS_TLS_URL ? process.env.REDIS_TLS_URL : process.env.REDIS_URL;
const redisDefaults = {
    tls: {
    // Heroku uses self-signed certificate, which will cause error in connection, unless check is disabled
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  };
  const client = redis.createClient(redisUrl, redisDefaults);


(async () => {
    client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
    await client.connect();
    console.log(`connected to redis ${redisUrl}`)
  })();

Comment: I have already checked that answer as well, When I try this code this is getting connected to my local redis not heroku redis, Kinldy check this on your local system, if you are able to connect to heroku-redis, I am not able to connect to heroku-redis

Answer (score 0):

In node-redis v4 the `host` and `port` should be inside a `socket` object, not directly on the main config object (see https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md):

```js
const client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
        host: process.env.host,
        port: process.env.port
    },
    password: process.env.password
});
```

Comment: const redis = require("redis");

const client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
        host: process.env.host,
        port: process.env.port
    },
    password: process.env.password
});
(async () => {
    client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
    await client.connect();
    console.log(`connected to redis `)
  })();

Comment: I am getting this error connect ECONNREFUSED 34.228.251.67:10080
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1142:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '34.228.251.67',
  port: 10080
}